# Getting data from disk (files) instead of memcache/datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I rely on an external service/API that returns json results. Urlfetch or that service is quite slow and the performance is very variable anyway. Also, if that service goes down, things go bad on my website. I have seen my pages loading in 1s or worse having no choice but return a 404 because that external service was having a bad time.

I was thinking of caching or storing those results in my app. These results for a given request don't change (or extremely rarely). So memcache is fast, but I could use some persistence such as datastore.

The general question is:

**Why not simply storing these json results on the disk in my app?**

Since I can't write to disk, I'd have to fetch/write the jsons on my machine (with a script/cron/whatever) and then deploy the app to update the files. I would probably not need to deploy more than once a day to update the json files.

Some considerations (and questions):

- With the smallest instance, reading from the disk takes 1.6ms to 5ms (seems equivalent to memcache)
- I do not recall seeing any quota for file reads. Is there something I forgot here?
- The disk is persistent, memcache is not
- Datastore is much slower and much more expensive.
- I don't know how well reading from the disk handles the load (wouldn't django's template.render() read from the disk and suffer from the same issue if there was one?)
- What if I have several instances running and a lot of traffic, will the concurrent file reads make it really slow? Anybody have metrics here?
- Is there another/better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the way App Engine works.  Whenever you need more processing power to handle your requests, a new "instance" is spun up.  Any given instance works like a VM - there's CPU resource and memory.  The only "disk" is the disk that contains the image to launch the instance (and all the other instances).  So instances don't have their own disk.

One really big reason you don't want to let each instance have its own disk is that you can't resolve the data.  What if instance 1 writes something, and instance 2 writes something else?  How do you merge those disks?  Or even route a request back to instance 1 or 2?

GAE is designed for massively parallel applications where writing to disk is not good enough, for performance and redundancy.  You're given the options of a datastore, blobstore, and memcache that are shared and somewhat synchronized between instances.

Reading from the static disk image in GAE is possible, but slow.  No good metrics, but there's been discussion of the slowness on the mailing list.  I've tried it myself for small data, and it's definitely slower than the datastore.

GCS is a disk-like alternative.  Still not fast.

If you don't need GAE's scaling, you could use an IaaS service like Amazon or some other VPS host that gives you access to the disk.  Keep in mind that even with Amazon, a network-mounted disk image could be slow too.

Comment: I understand the issues with writing to disk with several instances. But I don't quite see it for reading. Specifically I don't understand why reading (small) json files from the disk would be worse than django's template.render(). Aren't templates read from disk for every request? Here I'd read the json files directly from an id (no need to search or anything). You say it's slow but I measured 1.5ms to 5ms, this is not slower than memcache/datastore. Do you mean it's slow with a high load? If it was that bad, why wouldn't we cache our django html templates to memcache or something?

Comment: I do cache my django html templates :P  You're right, the disk can't be that slow since it loads the entire VM from disk, but I've seen it take 10s of ms to open and read a file, so it might depend on how big your entire filesystem is, and perhaps whether your file is somehow cached.  If the json data is static, the best way is: 1. Store it on on disk and deploy.  2. When your instance starts up, read the value into memory on your instance, 3. Serve from memory rather than disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store them locally, there are much better ways than doing it in your app's file system. You could use the datastore to store the JSON strings as blobs, or you can use the Blobstore directly. You mention that datastore is "expensive", but really it's not that expensive given that you'll only be reading from there if the data expires from memcache.

Comment: I gave a more detail comment to dragonx's answer below but it applies to your answer as well. Also, specific to what you're suggesting: why using blobstore or BlobProperty while I could use TextProperty (as far as I know this one is not index, which is fine with my case).

Comment: I didn't comment on the speed. My problem was more about making your development machine - and the deployment process - part of the production service, which seems unnecessarily fragile. Production tasks should happen in production. And yes, you could just as easily use TextProperty.